# how to compare values in set and rewrite them in python

Tags: python, set, overwrite

here is my code
I define an empty set, I want to compare
`se([i]) > 0`, then reassign the value of `se([i])` to be `0`. I am not able to do this
since `se([i])` is a set and cannot be compared to int. kindly help. I am new to python programming.

```
se =set()
se.update([8])
print (se)
for i in range (10):
    se.update([i])
    print type(se)
    print len(se)
print se
```

Comment: As a side note, why are you doing `se.update([i])` instead of just `se.add(i)`?

Comment: What does  “I want to compare se([i]) > 0, then reassign the value of se([i]) to be 0” mean?

Comment: More importantly: What do you mean "I want to compare se([i]) > 0"? There's no such thing as `se([i])`; `set`s aren't callable, nor are they indexable, so I can't guess what you're trying to do here. And likewise for the "reassign" part. What do you want to compare to > 0, and what do you want to assign to 0, and under what circumstances do you want to assign it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ultimately achieve. Neither comparing a set to an integer, nor trying to retrieve an item in it by access are things that make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to compare each element of `se` to `0`, and replace the ones that are `> 0` with `0`, that's pretty easy:

```
se = {0 if element > 0 else element for element in se}
```

Or, if you think about it:

```
se = {min(element, 0) for element in se}
```

You can't do this by indexing `se[i]`, because sets aren't indexable, because the whole point of sets (both mathematical and Python) is that they're unordered. And you definitely can't do it by calling `se([i])`, because you `set`s aren't functions, or other callable (function-like) things. If you really wanted to do it by mutating in place, you could:

```
for element in se.copy():
    if element > 0:
        se.remove(element)
        se.add(0)
```

(Notice the `se.copy()` there—you can't change the shape of a collection while iterating over it, so you need to iterate over a copy of it instead.)

Meanwhile, again, the whole point of a set is that it's unordered, which means adding `0` multiple times is exactly the same as adding it once. So:

```
>>> se = { -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 }
>>> print se
set([0, 1, 2, 3, -1, -3, -2])
>>> se = {min(element, 0) for element in se}
>>> print se
set([0, -2, -3, -1])
```

Or, using your code (with some of the extra `print` statements removed for brevity):

```
>>> se =set()
>>> se.update([8])
>>> print (se)
set([8])
>>> for i in range (10):
...     se.update([i])
>>> print se
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> se = {min(element, 0) for element in se}
>>> print se
set([0])
```